# Python numpy how to join numbers from array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am newbie in Python. I think I'm looking for something easy, but can't find.
I have an numpy binary array, e.g.:

```
 [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

And I want to do 2 things:

1. Join (?) all elements into one number, so result will be:

   ```
   x=101100011110
   ```
2. Next want to converse it into binary, so:

   ```
   xx=2846
   ```

I have an algorithm to do 2., but I don't know how to do 1. I can do it using loop, but is it possible to do it using numpy, without loop? My array will be huge, so I need the best option.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int(''.join(map(str, [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0])))
101100011110
```

Or with a little numpy:

```
>>> int(''.join(np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]).astype('|S1')))
101100011110
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @timgeb's answer, but if you're sure you want to use numpy calculations directly, you could do something like this:

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0])
exponents = np.arange(len(x))[::-1]
powers = 10**exponents
result = sum(powers * x)

In [12]: result
Out[12]: 101100011110
```

As pointed out by @Magellan88 in the comments, if you set `powers=2**exponents` you can get from 0 to your second part of the question in one sweep.

Comment: the powers should probably be 2**exponents, but other than that I would agree

Comment: That's if you want to get straight to binary from the initial array. It's a good point! I added a note on that to the answer.

Comment: I came to an old answer of yours in order to get away with the off-topic comment hat I love your avatar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want loop in first task then you can go with map method , I just wanted to show you can also try this :

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0])

int_con=str(array).replace(',','').replace(' ','').replace('[','').replace(']','')

print("Joined {}".format(int_con))

bin_to_de=0

for digit in int_con:
    bin_to_de=bin_to_de*2+int(digit)

print("Decimal conversion {}".format(bin_to_de))
```

output:

```
Joined 101100011110
Decimal conversion 2846
```